# extract data from elementor webhook with php

Tags: php, html, wordpress, webhooks, elementor

I'm trying to get the data elementor from a submission form to a MySql DataBase. I have already connected to the data base in a local way. But now that I want to get the data from the web page's webhook I can´t retrieve the data. Here's my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>


    <?php
        //Data Base connection info:
        $servername = "localhost";
        $username = "username"; 
        $password = "password";
        $dbName="dbName";

        ////////////////////////////Retrieved information from form ////////////////////////////////////////////
        $name=$email=$telephone=$message="";
                              ///////Data Obtained in the form:////////////
        if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        $name=$_POST["No Label name"];
        $email=$_POST["No Label email"];
        $telephone=$_POST["No Label phone"];
        $message=$_POST["No Label message"];;


        //////////////////////////////////////////// DATA BASE CONNECTION ///////////////////////////////////////


        // Create connection with DB.

        $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbName);
        //////////////////////////// Check connection ///////////////////////////////////
        if (!$conn) {
            die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
        }
        $sql="INSERT INTO TableName (Name, Email, Phone, Menssage ,Contacted) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?,0)";
        $stmt=$conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $name, $email, $telephone, $message);
        $stmt->execute();
        mysqli_close($conn);
        }

    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

*The "No Label name" came because i did not want to change how the web page looked. The request bin*
https://requestbin.com/ *showed me the labels of the array being sent*.

I have also tried this solution but it did't work:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<body>


    <?php
        //Data Base connection info:
        $servername = "localhost";// has to be changed to the actual host
        $username = "username"; 
        $password = "password";
        $dbName="dbName";//we need to add the data base name

        ////////////////////////////Retrieved information from form ////////////////////////////////////////////
        $name=$email=$telephone=$message="";
                              ///////Data Obtained in the form:////////////
        $Rawdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
        $data = json_decode($Rawdata, true); 
        $name=$data["No Label name"];
        $email=$data["No Label email"];
        $telephone=$data["No Label phone"];
        $message=$data["No Label message"];

        //////////////////////////////////////////// DATA BASE CONNECTION ///////////////////////////////////////


        // Create connection with DB.

        $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbName);
        //////////////////////////// Check connection ///////////////////////////////////
        if (!$conn) {
            die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
        }
        $sql="INSERT INTO TableName (Name, Email, Phone, Menssage ,Contacted) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?,0)";
        $stmt=$conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $name, $email, $telephone, $message);
        $stmt->execute();
        mysqli_close($conn);


    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

If their's any questions about the code or the variables please ask.
Also I have the question if elementors webhooks sends the data in json or as a normal POST method.
Regards

Answer (score 4):

The fields in the webhook form are passed through a class called Ajax_Handler defined in `wp-content/plugins/elementor-pro/modules/forms/classes/ajax-handler.php`.

Although I haven't poked around in there much, looking at what is received by my PHP server it sends two POST parameters, at least it does if I toggle the *Advanced Data* option to yes in the **Webhook** section:

Parameter 'form' is an array containing keys 'id' and 'name' which are properties of the Form that the webhook call originates from - the 'id' is usually auto-generated but could be set in the **Additional Options** area, and the 'name' is the *Form Name* property in the **Form Fields** section.

Parameter 'fields' is an array of the Form Fields themselves. Each Form Field you created appears as a key to another array which holds the following:

```
'id' => the form field ID you set in Elementor
'type' => the type of field (text, email etc.)
'title' => the label for the field
'value' => the actual value in the input element
'raw_value' => not sure how this differs from 'value'...
'required' => whether the field was marked as required.
```

So for example I have a form named NewsSubscriber with two fields 'email' and 'name' and a hidden field called 'fn' to tell the server what to do, so I get the following in my PHP script:

```
$_POST=>[
  'form' => [
    'id' => '5cbb571',
    'name' => 'NewsSubscriber'
  ],
  'fields' => [
    'email' => [
      'id' => 'email',
      'type' => 'email',
      'title' => 'Email Address',
      'value' => 'person@example.com',
      'raw_value' => 'person@example.com',
      'required' => '1'
    ],
    'name' => [
      'id' => 'name',
      'type' => 'text',
      'title' => 'Name',
      'value' => 'Bob Person',
      'raw_value' => 'Bob Person',
      'required' => '1'
    ],
    'fn' => [
      'id' => 'fn',
      'type' => 'hidden',
      'title' => 'Function',
      'value' => 'add',
      'raw_value' => 'add',
      'required' => '0'
    ]
  ]
]
```

So (with a few checks) I can extract the function as `$_POST['fields']['fn']['value']`, the email from `$_POST['fields']['email']['value']` and the name from `$_POST['fields']['name']['value']`

Comment: Absolute life saver! :-)

Comment: works, but note that you need to check "advanced data mode" in the webhook tab